# Google captcha Error : data:image/png;base64,undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-plugins

We are seeing below error and google captach is keep rotating , not sure how to solve an help is appreciated

[image]

```
GET data:image/png;base64,undefined  recaptcha__en.js:256
(anonymous function) recaptcha__en.js:256
M recaptcha__en.js:32
Vl recaptcha__en.js:255
Ul recaptcha__en.js:255
Sl.ed recaptcha__en.js:253
Rk recaptcha__en.js:216
f.Af recaptcha__en.js:263
hm recaptcha__en.js:262
fm.Jj recaptcha__en.js:261
(anonymous function) cb=gapi.loaded_0:121
vz cb=gapi.loaded_0:49
Iz cb=gapi.loaded_0:49
Jz cb=gapi.loaded_0:50
jz.Ei cb=gapi.loaded_0:43
```